# ¿Como concatenar un String con consulta SQL en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy escribiendo un script en php que realiza una consulta a una base de datos sql.

El resultado de esa consulta necesito concatenarlo con un string.

Ejemplo: la consulta a la base de datos me devuelve `"Cosme Fulanito"` y necesito concatenarlo con un string que diga `"Mi nombre es"` para que el resultado sea `"Mi nombre es Cosme Fulanito"`.

El resultado de consulta lo estoy almacenando en una variable y el string igual, ya trate con:

```
$consulta = "ejemplo de consulta";
$cadena = "Mi nombre es" ;
$nombre = $cadena . $consulta;
```

¿Como podría resolverlo?

Comment: Pero... ¿`Cosme Fulanito` lo recibes en la variable `$consulta` o en la variable `$nombre`?

Comment: En $consulta, ya lo corregi

Answer (score 1):

Así debería de funcionar

```
$consulta = "ejemplo de consulta";
$cadena = "Mi nombre es" ;
$nombre = $cadena .' '. $nombre;
```

Answer (score 1):

Para concatenar un string no tienes que guardarlo en una variable, puedes hacerlo asi:

```
echo 'Mi nombre es' . $nombre;
```